# How to use angular2 array filter?

Tags: angular, ionic2

```
import {Pipe} from '@angular/core';
```

After using `value.filter` it gives value.filter is not function Error.

Here Is my code snippet of Search.pipe.ts

```js
@Pipe({
    name: 'search'
})

export class Search {
    transform(value, args) {
        console.log("value"+JSON.stringify(value));
        console.log("args"+JSON.stringify(args));
        return value.filter(value => value.attendee_nm.indexOf(args) !== -1);
    }
}
```

Comment: You're probably passing the wrong value to your pipe. Can you show the part of the code where you are using the pipe?

Comment: FYI, [Array.filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) is plain JavaScript. It has nothing to do with Angular.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to implements PipeTransform this to work.
Value.filter will be a function if your value is of type array since filter only exists on array type.

Comment: I first though that PipeTransform is necessary, apparently not according to: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/pipes.html:  *The PipeTransform interface defines that method and guides both tooling and the compiler. It is technically optional; Angular looks for and executes the transform method regardless.* :)

Comment: thanks for the info.i was under the notion that transform method is from pipe transform interface.good to know angular 2 handles it internally

Comment: regarding your problem is value you are passing is an array type?

Comment: Re. the `PipeTransform` interface. What AJT_82 said is true of ALL class interfaces, not just `PipeTransform`. They are here to guide the developer/IDE, not to "make the code work". For instance, you don't need to add `implements OnInit` on a component class for the `ngOnInit()` method to be called. The method is called because it exists and it has the right name, that's all.

Comment: @AngularFrance Nice, thanks a lot for the info, did not know that! :)